# Using a variable in a VBA IF statement

Tags: excel, vba

I have a working IF statement in a VBA Module.
The IF statement checks a date in a table is between two dates and returns a TRUE or FALSE that can be used by a subsequent Pivot Table to sum values from the Table.  I am working with European dates.

```
 lColName.DataBodyRange.Formula = "=IF(AND([@Date] >=$G$1,[@Date] <=$H$1),""TRUE"",""FALSE"")"
```

The dates are in $G$1 and $H$1 in that sheet for ease of debugging but want to place them on another sheet where I have all the other reference data I use in the workbook.
So in this Module, before the IF statement, I have set those dates against two variables.

```
Worksheets("References").Activate
startdate = Range("I2").Value
enddate = Range("J2").Value
```

Repacing $G$1 and $H$1 with startdate and enddate errors. What syntax should I use to get the IF statement to work?
Thanks

Comment: There is no VBA `If` statement in your question. It is an Excel formula that your `If` is part of. Nothing to do with VBA.

Answer (score 0):

How about this ?

```
With Worksheets("References")
    lColName.DataBodyRange.Formula = "=IF(AND([@Date] >=" & .Range("I2").Value & ",[@Date] <=" & .Range("J2").Value & "),""TRUE"",""FALSE"")"
End With
```

Comment: Thanks. That certainly wrote what appeared to be the correct IF formulae but the result was not correct. I wanted to post two images to explain but cannot in a comment, I will post in answer.

Comment: If the column contents register as a valid formula then that's all I can do - it's for you, with access to _all_ of the data, to determine what the _correct_ formula might be

Comment: I tried all sorts of things but the IF statement only returned FALSE. In the end I altered the original which used the dates on the same sheet to using the dates on my References sheet with this and it worked ! "=IF(AND([@Date] >=References!$I$2,[@Date] <=References!$J$2),""TRUE"",""FALSE"")"